# Show the data that will be Edited in Drop Down List of a Modal View using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

Im planning to Show the Data on Database in the Drop Down List of a Modal View using Jquery

But it always return " "

This is my Html

```
          <p>
            <label for="ddlEditContactType">
                Contact Type</label>
            <span>
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlEditContactType", new SelectList(ViewBag.ContactTypeList, "ID", "Display_Value", workerContactType), "[Please Select]",
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"class","validate[required] inputLong"}
            })
            </span>
        </p>
```

This is my Jquery

```
var contactType = obj.closest("tr").find("input[name=contactType]").val();
$('#ddlEditContactType').attr('value', contactType);
```

Thanks in Advance :) I hope ill find the answers here , KUDOS! ;)

Comment: try putting in some alerts or console.log to figure out where its breaking.

Comment: cant see where it occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve by Changing

This

> $('#ddlEditContactType').attr('value', contactType);

to

```
    $("#ddlEditContactType option")
    .each(function () { this.selected = (this.text == contactType); });
```